# При form.submit() опускается проверка полей на required

Tags: javascript, submit, required

Есть форма с инпутом, который обьязателен для заполнения

```
<form action="" id="go">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="" placeholder="set-name" required="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

И если через javascript сделать submit, то форма отправляется, без проверки на required

```
document.getElementById("go").submit();
```

А если нажать на кнопку "Отправить" - тогда проверка есть, и не отправляет форму пока не заполнишь...

Почему так происходит, почему js не проверяет поля формы?

Chrome 57.0.2987.133

Firefox 52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При вызове метода `.submit()` проверка на валидность не осуществляется. Предполагается, что при ручной отправке это сделано самостоятельно. Потому не забываем вызывать метод `.checkValidity()` перед отправкой:

```js
let $form = document.getElementById('form'),
    $submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');

$submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if( $form.checkValidity() ) {
    $form.submit();
  } else {
    // ваша обработка ошибок
  }
});
```

Источник:

> [Метод submit](https://learn.javascript.ru/forms-submit#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-submit)

Answer (score 2):

Можно не вызывать событие submit, а имитировать событие нажатия кнопки, тогда проверка должна быть. С помощью jQuery это можно сделать так:

```
$("#go input[type=submit]").click();
```